# QWidget reports the same incorrect width value

Tags: qt, qt5, size, qwidget, qlayout

I have a custom widget class:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    // code
};
```

I add a lot of push buttons to a `QHBoxLayout`, and set that layout to the `MyWidget` object.
I want `MyWidget` widget to have the width of a widget contained in it (all such widgets have the same size).
So I overrode `sizeHint()`:

```
QSize MyWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    if (auto pLayout = layout())
    {
        auto pItem = pLayout->itemAt(0);
        //std::cout << pItem->widget()->width() << std::endl;
        if (pItem && pItem->widget())
            return QSize{ pItem->widget()->width(), QWidget::sizeHint().height() };
    }
    return QWidget::sizeHint();
}
```

Now, `pItem->widget()->width()` always reports the same value, no matter what size `pItem->widget()` is. What's the problem?

Comment: You could show an image of what you get and another of what you want to get, I think you are complicating yourself too much, maybe we could give you another solution.

Comment: _the same size_ or _the same width_?

Comment: The issue was that I was taking the widget's size while it was hidden. I've found another way to calculate its size - I set it somewhere else.